# Correctly setting Controller.User to custom IPrinciple

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I'm trying to use a custom implementation of IPrinciple. I've created a Membership and Role Provider and registered them in the web.config - and both work.

However, when I access the User property of the controller, it is still a `System.Web.Security.RolePrinciple`. Where am I supposed to set the User property to be my implementation?

I was hoping that ASP.NET would automatically use the MembershipProvider I specify in the web.config and set the current user for me. However, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2126070/784908 suggests I should set the HttpContext current user to my custom principle in Application_BeginRequest. Is this the right place? Is it early enough for role checking/model binding? Is there a risk it could break anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2126070/784908 suggests I should
>   set the HttpContext current user to my custom principle in
>   Application_BeginRequest. Is this the right place?

Yes, that's one possible place. Another, more MVCish place is to write a custom AuthorizeAttribute and set the principal in the AuthorizeCore method that you would override.